# Как в слайдере Swiper сделать автоматически заполняющийся прогрессбар

Tags: swiper, слайдер

Вот тут пытаюсь сделать, но пока все одновременно заполняются, а как сделать по очереди для каждого слайда? или может вообще надо по другому
https://codepen.io/dima2323/pen/WNabNKx

```
    const progressRows = document.querySelectorAll(".autoplay-progress span");
new Swiper('.popup__slider', {
                observer: true,
                observeParents: true,
                slidesPerView: 1,
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 5000,
                    disableOnInteraction: false,
                },
                navigation: {
                    prevEl: '.popup-button-prev',
                    nextEl: '.popup-button-next',
                },
                 on: {
                    autoplayTimeLeft(s, time, progress) {
                         progressRows.forEach(progressRow => {
                             progressRow.style.setProperty("--progress", 1 - progress);
                        });
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```